# Airflow Passing date Xcom variable to a sql file using RedshiftSQLOperator

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I want to pass the date value (from a variable) as partition column in sql file. The variable is not getting evaluated. The variable is stored in Xcom. Is there any better way to do .

Rendered template:

```
    TO 's3://opsake/prc/deldb/ldp_pipeline_hist/partiton_key=''{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='genExecParam', key='app_run_dt') }}''/'
   iam_role 'arn:aws20xxx:role/Re11dccc3role'
   allowoverwrite
  format as parquet
  maxfilesize 100 mb;, parameters: None
```

Code :
Here I am using the ds or inputdate

```
def genExecParam(**kwargs):
   if 'ds_date' in kwargs['dag_run'].conf:
      app_run_dt = (kwargs['dag_run'].conf['ds_date'])
   else:
      app_run_dt = kwargs['ds']
      var_dt = datetime.fromisoformat(kwargs['ds'])
      app_prev_run_dt = (var_dt + timedelta(days=-1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
      # (datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))+timedelta(days=-1)).strftime(date_format)
   app_run_id = datetime.now(timezone('UTC')).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
   kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='app_run_id', value=app_run_id)
   kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='app_run_dt', value=app_run_dt)
```

Dag:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.redshift import RedshiftSQLOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from pytz import timezone
import pendulum
from utils.dagUtils import *



localtz = pendulum.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')

# default arguments to DAG
default_args = {
    "owner": "delta",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2022, 7, 2, tzinfo=localtz),
    "email": [emalgrp],
    "email_on_failure": True,
    "email_on_retry": True,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "max_active_runs": 1,
    "catchup": False,
}
var_dt = '{{ ds }}'

with DAG(
        'extrse',
        default_args=default_args,
        description='extse',
        max_active_runs=1,
        schedule_interval= '0 10 * * *',
        catchup= False,
        tags=['env', 'prod'],
        on_success_callback=dag_success_callback,
        on_failure_callback=dag_failure_callback,
        template_searchpath ='/usr/local/airflow/dags/modules/'
) as dag:
    AppStart = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    var_ds_date = "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='genExecParam', key='app_run_dt') }}"
    var_ds_prev_date = "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='genExecParam', key='app_prev_run_dt') }}"
    app_run_id = "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='genExecParam', key='app_prev_run_dt') }}"
    genExecParam = PythonOperator(task_id='genExecParam', python_callable=genExecParam, provide_context=True)

    sourouse = RedshiftSQLOperator(task_id='sourouse',
        redshift_conn_id='deltn_id',
        sql=['prc_layer/sql/lighthract.sql'],
        params={"data_bucket_name": data_bucket_name,"prc_db_dir": prc_db_dir,"var_ds_date": var_ds_date})

AppStart >>genExecParam >>source_ld_lighthouse
```

Sql File:

```
UNLOAD ('select * from test.sales_report')
TO 's3://{{ params.data_bucket_name }}/{{ params.prc_db_dir }}/ldp_pipeline_hist/partiton_key={{ params.var_ds_date }}/'
           iam_role 'arn:awrole'
           allowoverwrite
          format as parquet
          maxfilesize 100 mb;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedshiftSQLOperator's `params` is not part of `template_fields`, so jinja syntax is not allowed in params.

Instead, `sql` is the part of `template_fields`, so it is possible to do like this.

```sql
UNLOAD ('select * from test.sales_report')
TO 's3://{{ params.data_bucket_name }}/{{ params.prc_db_dir }}/ldp_pipeline_hist/partiton_key={{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="genExecParam", key="app_run_dt") }}/'
           iam_role 'arn:awrole'
           allowoverwrite
          format as parquet
          maxfilesize 100 mb;
```

Small note, it might not be a good idea to name the python function and task variable as the same name. You might get some weird behavior.
You are overwriting your python function with

```py
genExecParam = PythonOperator(task_id='genExecParam', python_callable=genExecParam, provide_context=True)
# genExecParam is no longer your python function.
```

Comment: It worked out Thanks a lot. My question is how can I use var_ds_date = "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='genExecParam', key='app_run_dt') }}" .

Comment: If you are okay with writing the SQL directly in the DAG file, you can use `var_ds_date` but I don't think you can pass the jinja syntax from DAG to sql file with `RedshiftSQLOperator`.